# Rotating letters in a string so that each letter is shifted to another letter by n places

Tags: ruby

I have been tasked with coming up with a way of encoding a string. Among other things, I need to shift each letter by a given number but the transformed letter must be a letter (circular shift).

I have got the following code so far:

```
def play_pass(str, n)
  letters = ('a'..'z').to_a
  str.chars.map {|x| letters.include?(x.downcase) ? (x.ord + n).chr : x}.join
end
```

This works for most letters

My problem is that if I am trying to shift `y` by 2 places, I should get `a` but instead I get the character `[`

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
def play_pass(str, n)
  letters = ('a'..'z').to_a
  str.chars.map {|x| letters.include?(x.downcase) ? 
     letters[letters.find_index(x.down_case) + n - letters.size] : x}.join
end

p play_pass("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 2)
```

**Output**

```
"cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzab"
[Finished in 0.3s]
```

**How it works**

`letters` is an array of chars `a` to `z` just the way OP has in his code.
We iterate over all chars in `str`, and find its index in `letters` array.  Then we add `n` to that index to get the shifted character.  To avoid falling off the array, we subtract `letters.size` (in this case `26`), so that the our lookup into `letters` is done using value between `0` and `25`.

For example: In the scenario that OP pointed out, if the character to be shifted was `y`, then, adding 2 to its index in `letters` will give us shifted index `26` (`24` is index of `y` in `letters` array, `2` is number characters we are shifting in the test case) -  To make `letters` behave like circular array, and not encounter index out of bound type of exception, we subtract `letters.size` from `26` shifted index.  Thus, we get index `0`, which represents char `a` which is what we are interested in.

Another example is case of `a` -  Here the shifted index will be `0 + 2 = 2`. When we subtract `letters.size` from it, we get `-24`.  Ruby allows negative indexes wherein lookup of array element is done from reverse, and it will resolve to correct element.  Index `-1` is same as Index `(size-1)`, similarly, index value of `-size` is equal to index `0`.

Comment: What? 300ms to do this? What hardware do you run this on? A fridge? :)

Comment: :D I ran it on decent laptop with i7 processor + Windows 8.1 using sublime text 3

Comment: Explanation is needed, btw.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I am getting the error:  `block in play_pass': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
 from `map'
 from  `play_pass'
 from  `
'

Comment: Updated the code to include upper case characters in letters array, it was not working if input had upper case chars

Comment: @KVyas I am not sure what is the requirement for upper case chars.  Code above will not work for upper case inputs

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks for pointing it out.  I trying to figure that out.

Comment: Thank you! I saw where it was going wrong. This works. Thanks again, I am a newcomer to Ruby and it's great to have an explanation to go along with the solution

Answer (score 3):

Your mistake is that you just blindly shift characters and don't use your `letters` array to wrap around.

```
def play_pass(str, n)
  letters = ('a'..'z').to_a

  str.chars.map do |x| 
    if letters.include?(x.downcase)
      idx = letters.index(x)
      new_idx = (idx + n) % letters.length
      letters[new_idx]
    else
      x
    end
  end.join

end

play_pass('ay1', 2) # => "ca1"
```

The key to success here is the [**modulo** operator (%)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). We use to get an index of a substitution character from `letters` array. It guarantees that the index will always be within bounds of the array. Instead of going past the end, it wraps around.

Read up on it. It's useful in many places.

Comment: Thank you, I can see how this works, but I am getting a weird error that I don't understand - 'undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: You have a weird input that this code doesn't anticipate. What's the input?

Comment: Uppercase letters, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

Arrays have a `rotate` method:

```
def play_pass(str,n)
  abc = ("a".."z").to_a.join
  abc_rot = abc.chars.rotate(n).join
  str.tr(abc, abc_rot)
end

p play_pass("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 2)
# => "cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzab"
```

A negative `n` rotates the other way.

Answer (score 2):

Where your code goes wrong is when the shifted letter has a smaller character code than its original was, yet your code always adds a positive value to do the shift.  You first need to detect when you are in this situation (for example, if the shifted letter is greater than `z`), and then make the appropriate fix (hint: consider the difference between the character code you want and the one you are getting now).